Variadic template function arguments not accepted
The following code won't build, any feedback on the cause would be appreciated.
void bar(std::string str, int& a, int& b)
{
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void foo(std::function<void(T, Args...)> fcn, Args ... args)
{
    // Some code that calls fcn
}

void run()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    foo<std::string, int&, int&>(bar, a, b);
}

It is a modified implementation of the first solution proposed in this SO answer.
The IDE gives the following error on the line calling foo:

C++ template<class T, class... Args> void foo(std::function<void (T, Args...)> fcn, Args ...args)
no instance of function template "foo" matches the argument list
argument types are:
(void (std::string str, int &a, int &b), int, int)

Tested separately, it seems like passing a fcn argument with template arguments are fine. The issue seems to be with passing a function argument where the function can accept variadic template arguments.


& when I removed it, there was no error

#include <iostream>
#include <functional> 

void bar(std::string str, int a, int b)
{
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void foo(std::function<void(T, Args...)> fcn, Args ... args)
{
    // Some code that calls fcn
}


int main() {
    std::function<void(std::string, int, int)> func_1 = bar;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    foo(func_1, a, b);
    return 0;
}


If it is necessary to use Call by Reference, I tried it by giving a direct address and it worked in this case too.

#include <iostream>
#include <functional> 

void bar(std::string str, int* a, int* b)
{
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void foo(std::function<void(T, Args...)> fcn, Args ... args)
{
    // Some code that calls fcn
}


int main() {
    std::function<void(std::string, int*, int*)> func_1 = bar;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    foo(func_1, &a, &b);
    return 0;
}



Great, thanks. The func_1 line helps a lot.

Function (pointer) is not a std::function, so doesn't work for deduction.
You might make Ts... non deducible in that context
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void foo(std::function<void(T, std::type_identity_t<Args>...)> fcn, Args ... args)
{
    // Some code that calls fcn
}

Demo
or drop std::function completely
template<typename T, typename F, typename ... Args>
requires (std::is_invocable<F, T, Args...>::value)
void foo(F fcn, Args&& ... args)
{
    // Some code that calls fcn
}

Demo

Thanks! Is there a workaround that doesn't require c++20? It seems type_identity was added with c++20.

The same is true for std::is_invocable. Both answers are appreciated, regardless.

But deduction isn't happening if the template arguments are specified.

std::type_identity can be re-implemented easily.

requires usage can be replaced by auto foo(F f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::declval<T>(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...), void())

@DavidG: We provide the beginning, we cannot say that pack stop, i.e with template <typename... Ts> void bar(std::tuple<Ts...>);  bar<int>(std::tuple<int, char, float>{}) is valid.

Thanks all. Going off of the answer by serkan the following seems to work.
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> 

void bar(std::string str, int& a, int& b)
{
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void foo(std::function<void(T, Args...)> fcn, Args ... args)
{
    // Some code that calls fcn
}

int main() {
    std::function<void(std::string, std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::reference_wrapper<int>)> func_1 = bar;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    foo(func_1, std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
    foo((std::function<void(std::string, std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::reference_wrapper<int>)>)bar, std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
    return 0;
}

I'll run more tests, there might still be some changes needed.
